# Stitching 6 video files into one 360 video in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, 360-virtual-reality, picamera, hugin

I used 2 raspberry PIs to record 2 different videos in sync using a OSC server so the videos are perfectly in sync and I send them to a Linux server so I can stitch these videos and produce one 360 video file so far I have tried doing that on 2 videos just for testing purposes using two methods:
1- only ffmpeg:
By simply concatinating two videos into one but this doesn't produce a 360 video as seen here[image]

2- using ffmpeg and hugin following this tutorial (https://medium.com/@xorgol/stitching-multi-camera-360-video-an-open-source-workflow-bb8b1e72925):
The problem here is I needed to do this method on each video file I have and then concatenate both videos to produce this result[image]

The original video can be seen here its captured using the RPI camera module V2 using a lens that provide a resolution of 3280x2464.
[image]

I don't mind a bit of overlapping or anything I just need to produce a 360 video from 2 videos using two vamera with 180 degrees FOV and be able to view them using a 360 video player so your help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a batch file to tie all the steps together?